# Как разобрать XML в Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

В таблице есть столбец clob, в котором хранится текст XML такого вида:

```
<Address>
 <Element type="district">БРЕСТСКАЯ</Element>
 <Element type="region"></Element>
 <Element type="ctype" key="1">Город</Element>
 <Element type="city">КОБРИН</Element>
 <Element type="stype" key="1">Улица</Element>
 <Element type="street">СУВОРОВА</Element>
 <Element type="house">33</Element>
 <Element type="building"></Element>
 <Element type="flat">6</Element>
 <Element type="postcode">225306</Element>
</Address>
```

Хочется разобрать это силами SQL, получив в результате склейку значений.
В данном случае хочу получить на выходе

```
БРЕСТСКАЯ КОБРИН УлицаСУВОРОВА 33 6
```

Подскажите, как можно добиться такого результата?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with t as
(select 
'<Address>
 <Element type="district">БРЕСТСКАЯ</Element>
 <Element type="region"></Element>
 <Element type="ctype" key="1">Город</Element>
 <Element type="city">КОБРИН</Element>
 <Element type="stype" key="1">Улица</Element>
 <Element type="street">СУВОРОВА</Element>
 <Element type="house">33</Element>
 <Element type="building"></Element>
 <Element type="flat">6</Element>
 <Element type="postcode">225306</Element>
</Address>' as xml_ 
from dual)
SELECT  extractvalue(s.column_value, '/*/Element[@type=''district'']')||' '||
        extractvalue(s.column_value, '/*/Element[@type=''city'']')||' '||
        'Улица '||extractvalue(s.column_value, '/*/Element[@type=''street'']')||' '||
        extractvalue(s.column_value, '/*/Element[@type=''house'']')||' '||
        extractvalue(s.column_value, '/*/Element[@type=''flat'']') as VAL
FROM t, table(xmlsequence(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(t.xml_), '/Address'))) s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with x as (
  select xmltype('
<Address>
 <Element type="district">БРЕСТСКАЯ</Element>
 <Element type="region"></Element>
 <Element type="ctype" key="1">Город</Element>
 <Element type="city">КОБРИН</Element>
 <Element type="stype" key="1">Улица</Element>
 <Element type="street">СУВОРОВА</Element>
 <Element type="house">33</Element>
 <Element type="building"></Element>
 <Element type="flat">6</Element>
 <Element type="postcode">225306</Element>
</Address>') xfield
  from dual
)  
select address
from XMLTable('
  let $r := 
  <address>
    {$doc/Address/Element[@type="district"]},{$doc/Address/Element[@type="city"]},{$doc/Address/Element[@type="stype"]},{$doc/Address/Element[@type="street"]},{$doc/Address/Element[@type="house"]}, {$doc/Address/Element[@type="flat"]}
  </address> 
  return $r'
  passing (select xfield from x) as "doc"
  columns address varchar2(1000) path '/address'
);
```

> БРЕСТСКАЯ,КОБРИН,Улица,СУВОРОВА,33, 6

Answer (score 3):

Функция [`xmlSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions267.htm#SQLRF06170) объявлена устаревшей. Вместо неё рекомендуется пользоваться [`xmlTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232) в новом коде:

```sql
with data as (
    select xmlType('
    <Address>
        <Element type="district">БРЕСТСКАЯ</Element>
        <Element type="region"></Element>
        <Element type="ctype" key="1">Город</Element>
        <Element type="city">КОБРИН</Element>
        <Element type="stype" key="1">Улица</Element>
        <Element type="street">СУВОРОВА</Element>
        <Element type="house">33</Element>
        <Element type="building"></Element>
        <Element type="flat">6</Element>
        <Element type="postcode">225306</Element>
    </Address>
    ') as xml from dual
)
select pcode||' '||district||' '||ctype||' '||city||' '||stype||' '||street||' '||house||'/'||flat  
from data d 
cross join xmlTable ('/Address' passing d.xml columns
pcode    varchar2 (8)  path '/Address/Element[@type="postcode"]', 
district varchar2 (64) path '/Address/Element[@type="district"]', 
ctype    varchar2 (32) path '/Address/Element[@type="ctype"][@key="1"]', 
city     varchar2 (64) path '/Address/Element[@type="city"]', 
stype    varchar2 (16) path '/Address/Element[@type="stype"][@key="1"]',
street   varchar2 (64) path '/Address/Element[@type="street"]',
house    number        path '/Address/Element[@type="house"]', 
flat     number        path '/Address/Element[@type="flat"]' 
);
```

Вывод:

> 225306 БРЕСТСКАЯ Город КОБРИН Улица СУВОРОВА 33/6

Answer (score 0):

Основываясь на https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715997/1646082

Колонка у вас должна быть типа XMLTYPE(т.е. вам надо сделать конвертацию) и тогда можно выполнить SQL типа:

```
SELECT
  extractvalue(xmlcol, '/*/Element') txtaddress
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Колонка типа XMLTYPE в таблице совсем не обязательна, CLOB замечательно приводится к XMLTYPE на лету.